# Nested function calls in Perl

Tags: perl

I've had to edit some Perl scripts for my work. I had never written a single line of Perl but I could get my thing working, until I bumped into a weird issue. Consider the following function

```
sub trim {
    my $s = shift; 
    $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
    return $s 
}
```

with the two following ways of calling it :

```
my $previousVersionHash = readline( *CONFIG );
$previousVersionHash = trim($previousVersionHash);
$maxClients = readline( *CONFIG );
```

and

```
my $previousVersionHash = trim(readline( *CONFIG ));
$maxClients = readline( *CONFIG );
```

In the first case, it works fine but with the second snippet I get warnings and `$maxClients` is empty instead of containing the second line of the `CONFIG` file.

Why this strange behaviour ? Note that this also happened when I used `sub trim($)`. By the way, I don't know the difference between those two declarations but this is documented so I could take a look if it matters for this question.

Comment: The problem shouldn't have happened if you said `sub trim($)`.  That said, learning to cope with sub calls giving list context to their args would be better than messing with prototypes, so `trim(scalar readline...)` is preferred.

Comment: If it wasn't such a pain for me to test this I would try adding back the parameter list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl will let the function it calls now if it wants an list or a scalar returned. You check this with [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html). `readline` reads all the lines into an array when you call it in list context, like you do in your second example.

The second way is calling it like this, since (like @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment says) arguments to user-defined subroutines are always evaluated in list context (assuming no prototypes):

```
my @array = readline( *CONFIG );
trim(@array);
```

So here all the rest of the lines of `*CONFIG` is put into the array `@array`. Your `trim` function discards all other values than the first of them.

To solve this and force the call to trim to be in scalar context do like this:

```
my $previousVersionHash = trim(scalar(readline( *CONFIG )));
```

or continue to call it like you do.

To update `trim` to support arrays you could try something like:

```
sub trim {
    my @a;
    foreach my $s (@_) {
        $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
        push @a, $s;
    }
    return @a;
}
```

Comment: Ok that's cool, so I can apply the trim function to all the lines if I want, and then simply read from the array. That would make the rest of my code slighly nicer :) Cheers !

Comment: Context is a confusing but powerful feature in Perl, and not a feature you are likely to have encountered in any other language.

Comment: Unless it is going to pass an array to `trim` ? I'm going to check

Comment: `s/array context/list context/`. Also, I think you left out the key point here: arguments to user-defined subroutines are always evaluated in list context (assuming no prototypes).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thank you. Updated my answer. I did tell that the sub was evaluated in list context, even if I didn't spell it out.

Comment: Thanks guys :) At least now I know about this. Not that I get to use Perl every day, but it may come handy in the future